# Can someone look at my code to help and a validation technique to make it only enter between 0 and 120 on my variables?

Tags: python

```
def readFromFile():    
    clientID = input("Enter your clientID: ")
    clientFile = open("clientIntensity.txt","r")
    for record in clientFile:
        if record.startswith(clientID):
            print ("Your intensity is", record[6:14])
            intensity = record[6:10]

            if intensity == "High":
                print(" Running \n Swimming \n Aerobics \n Football \n Tennis")
            else:
                print(" Walking \n Hiking \n Cleaning \n Skateboarding \n Basketball")

    clientFile.close()

readFromFile()

def Time():
    Running = int(input("Please enter the ammount of minutes you spent Running: "))
    Swimming = int(input("Please enter the ammount of minutes you spent Swimming: "))
    Aerobics = int(input("Please enter the ammount of minutes you spent doing Aerobics: "))
    Football = int(input("Please enter the ammount of minutes you spent playing Football: "))
    Tennis = int(input("Please enter the ammount of minutes you spent playing Tennis: "))
Time()

print(clientID)
print("The ammount of time spent exercising this week is",Running+Swimming+Aerobics+Football+Tennis)
```

This is the code I have and I keep getting the syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Controlled Assessment\Recorder.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(clientID)
NameError: name 'clientID' is not defined:
```

can anyone help? I need it so that it will print the clientID previously entered by the user at the start of the code. Also can someone help with a validation technique to make it so the user can only enter numbers between 0 and 120 for the Activities varibales e.g "Running"

Comment: It's best to make two separate questions when you have two separate issues.

Comment: You need to return the `clientID` from `readFromFile()`  and set a variable when you call it

Comment: How would I do that user2097159?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clientId = ""
Running = -1
Swimming = -1
Aerobics = -1
Football = -1
Tennis = -1

def readFromFile():
    global clientID
    clientID = input("Enter your clientID: ")
    clientFile = open("clientIntensity.txt","r")
    for record in clientFile:
        if record.startswith(clientID):
            print ("Your intensity is", record[6:14])
            intensity = record[6:10]

            if intensity == "High":
                print(" Running \n Swimming \n Aerobics \n Football \n Tennis")
            else:
                print(" Walking \n Hiking \n Cleaning \n Skateboarding \n Basketball")

    clientFile.close()

readFromFile()

def my_input(event):
    num = -1
    while not 0 <= num <= 120:
        num = int(input("Please enter the ammount of minutes you spent " + event + ": "))
    return num

def Time():
    global Running, Swimming, Aerobics, Football, Tennis
    Running = my_input('Running')
    Swimming = my_input("Swimming")
    Aerobics = my_input("Aerobics")
    Football = my_input("Football")
    Tennis = my_input("Tennis")
Time()

print(clientID)
print("The ammount of time spent exercising this week is",Running+Swimming+Aerobics+Football+Tennis)
```

Comment: Thanks Malik that is really helpful once again :) you're life saver

Comment: Did it work perfectly? What about the constraint you wanted? Does that work and do you understand it?

Comment: Oh sorry yeah I tested by putting '130' and it didn't give an error

Comment: Isn't it supposed to give an error like if I put something in their higher than 120? But it doesn't any ideas?

Comment: No it just keeps asking you for a number between 0 and 120.

Comment: That's the purpose of the `while` loop in the `my_input` function. It ensures that the user will enter a number in that range without an error.

Comment: Oh I see I need it so that when I enter the number it cant be anything below 0 or above 120 would you have any ideas?

Comment: Also I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Controlled Assessment\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    Time()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Controlled Assessment\test.py", line 28, in Time
    Running = my_input('Running')
NameError: global name 'my_input' is not defined

Comment: Try now Mike with the edits I made in the code. Basically this means, we called `my_input` before it is defined because Python runs from top to bottom.

Comment: Yes Works not and repeats if I enter a value higher than 120 Cheers :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: Sure thing dude :) you're truly helpful

Answer (score 0):

`clientId` is defined within the local namespace of your function `readFromFile`.

You then try to call it with `print` in the global namespace, where it doesn't exist.

It would be best to return clientId to a variable as:

```
def readFromFile():    
    clientID = input("Enter your clientID: ")
    with open("clientIntensity.txt","r") as clientFile:
        for record in clientFile:
            if record.startswith(clientID):
                print ("Your intensity is", record[6:14])
                intensity = record[6:10]

                if intensity == "High":
                    print(" Running \n Swimming \n Aerobics \n Football \n Tennis")
                else:
                    print(" Walking \n Hiking \n Cleaning \n Skateboarding \n Basketball")

    return clientID

clientID = readFromFile()

... # your time function here

print(clientID)
```

This runs the code as is, but returns the clientID to a variable, allowing it to be declared in the global namespace (as whatever variable you returned it to, in this case still `clientID`). This can then be passed to print.

It's also worth noting that the way you are reading the file is unpythonic, it is better to use the `with` clause, which is safer then using `file.open()` (I've used the `with` clause in the code above)

Comment: Ah Thank You Scironic! Works now :)

Answer (score 0):

@MikeStainer. Add this at the beginning of your code:

```
clientId = ""
Running = -1
Swimming = -1
Aerobics = -1
Football = -1
Tennis = -1
```

At the beginning of the `readFromFile` function, add `global clientId`
At the beginning of the `Time` function, add `global Running, Swimming, Aerobics, Football, Tennis`. This allows the functions to access global variables.

If you want to force a value between 0 and 120, simply use a while loop, reassigning the variables until they satisfy such a constraint.

Comment: Before in the global scope.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but do you think you can show me as code?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add an answer below in a few minutes.